# From QDateTime to correct json

Tags: c++, mysql, json, qt

I have timestamp column in my mysql table. I want to read date value and write it in QJsonObject.

```
jsonObject["date"] = query.value(6).toDateTime().toString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

That is working, but I have python-tests for my program.

> error: Attribute < date> from API response (value=u'2014-00-01 00:00:01') dont match test object (value='2014-01-01 00:00:01')

That is mean, that I should to change something in date-converting.
What should I change?

Comment: Does it work using something like `jsonObject.insert("date", QJSonValue::fromVariant(your_qdatetime_object));`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to me as if the Python program is expecting an ASCII string and is given a unicode string.

You could try

```
jsonObject["date"] = query.value(6).toDateTime().toString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss").toAscii();
```

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that you're using "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss". Note that the uppercase "MM" returns the day of the month while the lowercase "mm" returns the minute.